# Tablet keyboard issue while typing on EditText

Tags: android, keyboard

Currently I started to work with the **Tablet** and here I am facing the issue which is unknown to me.

Here when I am clicking on the **EditText** then it is focused and I can see which EditText is being focused here.
Like this.
[image: img]

See above the Qty column edit text is focused. This is working perfectly fine.

**Here is the problem**

```
 When I am trying to write any digit on the keyboard then the selected 
EditText gets hidden by the keyboard. I can still type in the EditText.
```

**Please make sure.**

```
I can still type in the EditText. 
But can't see while typing. This is the issue i am facing.
```

Here is another screen shot when I am writing anything on edittext.

[image: img2]

I want to see the edit text at the time of typing.

Kindly help me out to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You mean if your keyboard is displaying at that time your edittext is hidden, am i right?

Comment: Nope! when the edit text is clicked then keyboard is opened and edit text is not hidden. It gets hidden when i type any thing on edittext

Comment: post your xml file and some code, so we can help you more.

Comment: Hi Narendra, i have same problem. have you solve this problem ?

Comment: @SBJ Is your name Sebistain?

Comment: @SBJ I was getting suggestion for adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"          into the activity.But it was not working for me. I have created the custom keyboard for that,which shows only numbers in lower screen. I know this is not the solution,but I was not able to find that. Hope you will try and find out. If you got anything then please add your answer here. I will appriciate your answer